# How to disable the use of acronyms for one specific term

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package in Latex for all my acronyms/abbreviations. However, now I would like to disable the use of one specific acronym, because I do not use if often anyway. But instead of changing all `\gls{xyz}` to the normal term or to `\acrlong{xyz}`, I would prefer some sort of switch in my acronym definition (`\newacronym{}{}{}`), in case I change my mind later. Of course, this acronym should not be listed in the glossary if I disable it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1: Create an "Ignored Glossary"

An ignored glossary is defined using `\newignoredglossary`. Any entry assigned to it has the hyperlinks disabled by default. Ignored glossaries don't have associated indexing files and are skipped by iterative commands like `\printglossaries`.

It's a bit tricky using multiple acronym styles with just the base `glossaries` package, but it is possible provided the entries are in different glossaries:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}

\newignoredglossary{ignored}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{dua}
\newacronym[type=ignored]{ha}{ha}{hectare}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{mi}{mi}{mile}

\defglsentryfmt[ignored]{\GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{dua}}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{ha} and \gls{mi}.

Next use: \gls{ha} and \gls{mi}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: First use: hectare and mile (mi). Next use: hectare and mi. Acronyms mi mile. 1]

With the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package, the abbreviation styles are set according to the `category` (not `type`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronyms,postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\newignoredglossary{ignored}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[ignored]{long-noshort}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym[type=ignored,category=ignored]{ha}{ha}{hectare}

\newacronym{mi}{mi}{mile}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{ha} and \gls{mi}.

Next use: \gls{ha} and \gls{mi}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

(This produces the same result as before.)

### Method 2: Entry Counting

This method uses `\glsenableentrycount` and `\cgls` instead of `\gls` to count the number of times the entry is referenced and only indexes the entry if it's referenced more than once.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\glsenableentrycount

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newacronym{ha}{ha}{hectare}
\newacronym{mi}{mi}{mile}

\begin{document}
First use: \cgls{ha} and \cgls{mi}.

Next use: \cgls{mi}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Since the total can only be obtained at the end of the document, this requires a slightly modified build process. If the document is called `myDoc.tex`:

```
pdflatex myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

[image: First use: hectare and mile (mi). Next use: mi. Acronyms mi mile. 1]

With `glossaries-extra`, you can use `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting`, which redefines `\gls` to behave like `\cgls`, allows you to specify the trigger value (if the total count is greater than this value `\gls` behaves normally) and indicates what categories should be affected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronyms,postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{acronym}{1}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{ha}{ha}{hectare}
\newacronym{mi}{mi}{mile}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{ha} and \gls{mi}.

Next use: \gls{mi}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

This again requires:

```
pdflatex myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

(The result is the same as before.)

Comment: Having some trouble getting this working on Overleaf, which seems to use latexmk internally. If I do `\glsenableentrycount` and `\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{entrycount}{2}`, I still get all the entries. If I do `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{abbreviation}{1}`, I get way fewer entries than it should have. Hmm... Maybe I need to post another question

Comment: Figured it out after a decent amount of troubleshooting. Turns out `\usepackage[shortcuts,abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}` wouldn't work, but `\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries-extra}` or `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}` does. Not sure why `[abbreviations]` would cause issues. It's been so long I forgot why I loaded it in the first place..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. Here is one example with the acronym/abbreviation for hectares (ha):

```
\newacronym[\glsshortpluralkey=ha]
{ha}{ha}{hectare}
```

Now, I do not want to use it anymore. Instead, the long form should always be used and it should not appear in the glossary. So I have to make several changes: First, I redefine the short form to be the same as the long form. Then I say it should always use the short form (which is now the long form), because otherwise the first appearance will be like this: hectares (hectares). And then I move this acronym to an undefined glossary, because I do not want it to appear in the real glossary:

```
\newacronym[\glsshortpluralkey=hectares]
{ha}{hectare}{hectare}
\glsmoveentry{ha}{hidden} 
\glsunset{ha}
```

It is working for now, but it is not pretty. For example, if I now click on "hectare" in the PDF, it jumps to my first page. Normally it would jump to the glossary, but "hectare" is now in the nonexisting glossary called "hidden". So I would still appreciate better solutions ;)